# How to find specific line of data in array

Tags: javascript

I basiaclly have a block of text that I put into a array , how would i be able to find a specific value and return the full line. something like
array['bob 123'.'joe 112','sam 888']
if (array.contains('joe')){
log the full joe 112
}

Comment: `arr.find(e => e.includes('joe'))`

Comment: Thanks i been trying to get that to work for like an hour and just couldn't get it.

Comment: can you elaborate? What do you mean with "full line"? Do you want to return the full line of the original text? Or just the one item of the array, that contains "joe" (or whatever)

Comment: I needed the full line of the text containing a specific word. like im searching for names and numbers in a array. I just totally forgot about .find()

Answer (score 1):

You can use find function.

```
array.find(a => a.includes("joe"));
```